# Failed to load, Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Tags: spring, angular, http, http-get

I have http get method called by client side to the server, but when ran it, the method is OPTIONS, here is the output i am seeing in Chrome Dev tools, for the GET Method,

```
Request URL: http://localhost:9090/area
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: [::1]:9090
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response headers,

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4201
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 20 Mar 2018 18:49:59 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

and Request headers are,

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:9090
Origin: http://localhost:4201
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36
```

Why the GET method is not getting called, i know there are already some answers here, but i did not understand well, can some one please help me for clear understandig? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `OPTIONS` request is what is called a preflight request from the browser. In a simple way is basically the browser sending an initial request to the server asking for permission to then do a `GET` or `POST` or any other verb. This happens whenever a request needs permissions to be executed. If the server replies saying you have permissions to run the request you intend to, it will then perform the initial request (`GET` in this case). If the `OPTIONS` request is denied, it will not execute any subsequent request. You can see it as a way of testing the waters for requests :)

The reasons to be denied may be several. You might not have the correct headers, you might be missing authentication or authentication token, and so on.

From what I can see on your requests you are doing the requests from `localhost` to `localhost`. That will cause you problems with `CORS`.

[Here’s](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) a link on how to configure `CORS` for `spring` ( the server you said you are using in the comments below )

Comment: Thanks for the response, the headers are correct as per angular HttpClient Module, i am not getting other errors.

Comment: Do you have other way of testing the server call? Through postman or something similar, so you can rule out an issue with the server itself?

Comment: Yes, I have tested through Postman, there it is working fine.

Comment: Do you have access to the server log? Reason for the 500 should be there.

Comment: Did you use OPTIONS also with Postman? If you used GET it does not send OPTIONS as it isn't a cors request like in a browser.

Comment: As I suspected. I believe the problem is because you are running it locally on your localhost. You need to configure the CORS on your server app to accept the requests.

Comment: Yeah can be the server just doesn't know how to respond to options correctly

Comment: Try the same but change get to options

Comment: What are you using for the server? Expressjs?

Comment: For OPTIONS, the output is not printed.

Comment: I am using JAVA for server, developing in spring

Comment: You need to configure it for CORS to accept the same verbs/headers you are sending in the request. I’m sure there’s plenty of tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: How to configure CORS on the server, I tried @CrossOrigin in the controller class, but it did not help.

Comment: @HugoNoro , i have searched but nothing helped me, please help me.

Comment: I believe that will need to be done on the spring level. The server itself has to accept it otherwise it won’t even reach your classes or your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the knowledge. It helped me to get some idea. Please post if you find some link on configuring CORS.

Comment: @HugoNoro , Thank You very much.

Comment: Always glad to help. Please don’t forget to check as answered to help others in the future